# Error: invalid address during getBalance and send Raw Transaction

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, balances

Im using web3.js to retrieve the balance for the main account on my geth server

I set:

```
  let provider = new web3.providers.HttpProvider(ethereumNode)
  web3.setProvider(provider)

  if (!web3.isConnected()) {
    console.error('Ethereum - no conection to RPC server')
  } else {
    // is connected
    console.log('Ethereum - connected to RPC server')
  }


web3.eth.defaultAccount = from // from is my account on geth

// When goes to this line I get  Error: invalid address 
console.log("balance ", web3.eth.getBalance())
```

Besides this, I m trying to broadcast a raw transaction where it gets the same error

> Error: invalid address

however If I run the same raw transaction on https://ropsten.etherscan.io/pushTx it works fine.

any ideas what is happening? I have the feeling is a problem on my geth server.

error stack on getBalance()

```
 Error: invalid address
     at inputAddressFormatter (.../node_modules/web3/lib/web3/formatters.js:271:11)
    at .../node_modules/web3/lib/web3/method.js:89:28
    at Array.map (native)
    at Method.formatInput (.../node_modules/web3/lib/web3/method.js:88:32)
    at Method.toPayload (.../node_modules/web3/lib/web3/method.js:114:23)
    at Eth.send [as getBalance] (.../node_modules/web3/lib/web3/method.js:139:30)
    at .../server/src/batches/export2contract.js:80:40
    at writeContract (.../server/src/batches/export2contract.js:61:10)
    at .../server/src/batches/export2contract.js:190:5
    at Array.forEach (native)
```

Error stack on sendTransaction:

```
   Error: invalid address
    at inputAddressFormatter (.../node_modules/web3/lib/web3/formatters.js:271:11)
    at inputTransactionFormatter (.../node_modules/web3/lib/web3/formatters.js:97:20)
    at .../node_modules/web3/lib/web3/method.js:89:28
    at Array.map (native)
    at Method.formatInput (.../node_modules/web3/lib/web3/method.js:88:32)
    at Method.toPayload (.../node_modules/web3/lib/web3/method.js:114:23)
    at Eth.send [as sendTransaction] (.../node_modules/web3/lib/web3/method.js:139:30)
    at .../server/src/batches/export2contract.js:135:32
    at writeContract (.../server/src/batches/export2contract.js:61:10)
    at .../server/src/batches/export2contract.js:190:5
```

Comment: Well , did you try like this web3.eth.getBalance(from)  ?

Comment: yes and it works

Comment: Ok...great !  Is this what you are looking for ?

Comment: nope, I updated the question with more details.

Comment: and what is from ? I assume it is an valid account address and also make sure geth is running .

Comment: from is an address where geth has access, it was created on geth server

Comment: It should be an address some thing like this "0x8888f1f195afa192cfee860698584c030f4c9db1" , can you console it in log and see if you see an address in from variable ?

Comment: yes of course there is an address string, I just dont wanna show which address here.

Comment: Ok,So you have an address and you are geth is running and it still shows Error: invalid address..  strange..from the documentation it should work..  https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethgetbalance

Comment: What does the geth log shows in console when you invoke web3.eth.getBalance() ?

Comment: I've updated the question with the stack error

Comment: @ErnaneLuisPaixão How do you broadcast the raw transaction? It has to be something like `web3.eth.sendRawTransaction('0x12341....')` (look at https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendrawtransaction).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like from is not a valid address.

Looking at the stacktrace, in [web3's formatters.js](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/develop/lib/web3/formatters.js)

```
var inputAddressFormatter = function (address) {
    var iban = new Iban(address);
    if (iban.isValid() && iban.isDirect()) {
        return '0x' + iban.address();
    } else if (utils.isStrictAddress(address)) {
        return address;
    } else if (utils.isAddress(address)) {
        return '0x' + address;
    }
    throw new Error('invalid address');
};
```

line 271 is "utils.isAddress(address)" and [utils can be found here](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/blob/develop/lib/utils/utils.js).

You might want to try calling [web3.isAddress(from)](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3isaddress) and seeing if it validates.